# How does pandoc-citeproc sort citations?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, csl

I have a pandoc-style Markdown text where I cite two papers by the same author in the same place:

```
Lorem ipsum [@Author2000;@Author2001] dolor sit amet.
```

This is rendered as

> Lorem ipsum (Author 2001, 2000) dolor sit amet.

Why are these citations sorted this way, contradicting the sequence in my text, contradicting author-year sorting, and contradicting the sequence in which they appear in the list of references? How can I change this? Is it possible to switch off any kind of sorting and keep the order in which I specify the citations?

More information: The text is converted by pandoc with the options `--filter pandoc-citeproc --csl=elsevier-harvard.csl` into latex and then processed with xelatex. The csl file can be downloaded from [Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/styles/elsevier-harvard). Pandoc is v1.13.2, pandoc-citeproc is v0.6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In-text citation formatting is defined by your CSL between `<citation></citation>` tags. The sorting of your citations is defined between the `<sort></sort>` tags. The CSL you are using sorts by author and then by descending date issued - (Author 2001, 2000):

```
<citation ...>
    <sort>
        <key macro="author"/>
        <key macro="issued" sort="descending"/>
    </sort>
    ...
</citation>
```

To sort by author and then by ascending date issued - (Author 2000, 2001):

```
<citation ...>
    <sort>
        <key macro="author"/>
        <key macro="issued" sort="ascending"/>
    </sort>
    ...
</citation>
```

To not sort the citations, just remove everything between the `<sort></sort>` tags.

```
<citation ...>
    <sort>
    </sort>
    ...
</citation>
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Do you think this is a bug, or can you conceive of any reason why one would want references to be sorted by descending date?

Comment: @A.Donda Dates should be ascending according to [this resource](http://www.isa-sociology.org/publ/sociopedia-isa_harvard-style-guidelines.pdf), so you could make a pull request at the [csl repository](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles)