# Alphabetically sort special characters in pandoc-citeproc bibliography

Tags: special-characters, pandoc, bibliography, csl, pandoc-citeproc

I hope I'm not repeating a question, but I've searched high and low and haven't found any answers to something I'm sure other users of pandoc have encountered. (The references to this topic I have found are concerned with pandoc to LaTeX, whereas this is simple pandoc to .html / .rtf / etc conversion.) It seems that the pandoc-citeproc processor does not know what to do with special characters and diacritics, either unusual ones (e.g. ʿ) or common (e.g. á), and places them them all after "z" when creating its bibliographies. Since my typical bibliography bristles with special characters, it would be great to know if there's a workaround to manually modify the sorting order, or neutralize the special characters -- in the MWE I have below, for example, to tell it to sort ʿAal as though it were "Aal" and Áberforth as though it were "Aberforth", so that they show up above Amber.

Here is my MWE:

```
---
csl: chicago-note-bibliography.csl
references:
- id: Amber2000
  type: book
  author:
  - family: Amber
    given: Rodrigo
  issued:
  - year: '2000'
  title: Book 1

- id: Aberf2000
  type: book
  author:
  - family: Áberforth
    given: Rodrigo
  issued:
  - year: '2000'
  title: Book 2

- id: Aal2000
  type: book
  author:
  - family: ʿAal
    given: Rodrigo
  issued:
  - year: '2000'
  title: Book 3
...

This is my MWE.[@Amber2000] I want to see how it handles diacritics[@Aberf2000] and special characters.[@Aal2000]
```

Running `pandoc mwe.md -o test.html --filter=pandoc-citeproc`, I get the following output:

```html
<p>This is my MWE.<span class="citation"><a href="#fn1" class="footnoteRef" id="fnref1"><sup>1</sup></a></span> I want to see how it handles diacritics<span class="citation"><a href="#fn2" class="footnoteRef" id="fnref2"><sup>2</sup></a></span> and special characters.<span class="citation"><a href="#fn3" class="footnoteRef" id="fnref3"><sup>3</sup></a></span></p>
<div id="refs" class="references">
<div id="ref-Amber2000">
<p>Amber, Rodrigo. <em>Book 1</em>, 2000.</p>
</div>
<div id="ref-Aberf2000">
<p>Áberforth, Rodrigo. <em>Book 2</em>, 2000.</p>
</div>
<div id="ref-Aal2000">
<p>ʿAal, Rodrigo. <em>Book 3</em>, 2000.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footnotes">
<hr />
<ol>
<li id="fn1"><p>Amber, <em>Book 1</em>. <a href="#fnref1">↩</a></p></li>
<li id="fn2"><p>Áberforth, <em>Book 2</em>. <a href="#fnref2">↩</a></p></li>
<li id="fn3"><p>ʿAal, <em>Book 3</em>. <a href="#fnref3">↩</a></p></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

As you can see, it sorts the bibliography Amber, Áberforth, ʿAal. Any ideas?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902783/how-does-pandoc-citeproc-sort-citations

Comment: @mb21 Thanks for your suggestion! I tested it, but the problem with removing the `<sort>` keys altogether is that then the bibliography items appear in the order they are cited in the document, i.e., they're not sorted at all. 

I think the problem must lie in the way the special characters are processed; it might be a CSL issue, although I don't see any way to control that in the .csl file.

Comment: hm... maybe ask on the pandoc-discuss mailing list as well.. not sure if the CSL spec or pandoc-citeproc implementation is to blame for the sorting...

Comment: Details of sorting behavior (beyond variables and descending/ascending) is not specified in the CSL specs so this would be for the pandoc list

Comment: Thanks! I'll look through the list and see what I find, and loop them in if nothing turns up.